# Fish Pond Simulation: Homework, where am I going wrong?

Tags: java

This is a multipart question.

Restrictions:

- can't use `.clone()`, or `Collections`, or `System`.
- can't change to a different object type (I mean I can't change the `ArrayList` to a `List` or what not).

I think my problem might be that I haven't grasped exactly how to throw exceptions.
Not sure though.

Here is a part of the assignment that I'm stuck on.

> Adds the fish f to the fish list, if possible.
>
> First checks if the landscape in the fish's location is equal to ROCK.
>   If it is, then the fish is not added to the list.  Instead, throws an
>   IllegalFishPositionException, passing 
>   `IllegalFishPositionException.FISH_OVER_ROCK` to the constructor.
>
> Next checks for another fish (distinct from the parameter) that is in
>   the same location as the parameter.  If one is found, then the fish is
>   not added to the list.  Instead throws an IllegalFishPositionException,
>   passing `IllegalFishPositionException.TWO_FISH_IN_ONE_PLACE` to the
>   constructor.
>
> Otherwise, adds the parameter to the fish list.

```
public void addFish(Fish f) {
    ArrayList <Fish> addFish = new ArrayList <Fish>( fish );

    if ( landscape[ f.getRow() ][ f.getCol() ] == ROCK ) {
        throw new IllegalFishPositionException(
                IllegalFishPositionException.FISH_OVER_ROCK );
    }
    for ( Fish f1 : addFish ) {
        if ( ( f1.getRow() == f.getRow() && 
                f1.getCol() == f.getCol() ) || f1 == f ) {
            throw new IllegalFishPositionException(
                    IllegalFishPositionException.TWO_FISH_IN_ONE_PLACE );
        }
    }
    for ( Fish f2 : addFish ) {
        if ( ( f2.getRow() != f.getRow() && 
                f2.getCol() != f.getCol() ) && 
                landscape[ f.getRow() ][ f.getCol() ] != ROCK ) {
            fish.add( f );
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the second method that seems logical to me, but is failing on tests.

```
/* Checks the specified location to see if it has a rock, fish, or plant 
 * in it. If so, returns false; if it is just water, returns true. */
public boolean isSpaceAvailable(int r, int c) {
    if ( landscape[r][c] == ROCK ) {
        return false;
    }
    for ( Fish f : fish ) {
        if ( ( f.getRow() == r ) && ( f.getCol() == c ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    for ( Plant p : plants ) {
        if ( ( p.getRow() == r ) && ( p.getCol() == c ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have a couple of other methods that are dependent on addFish, so if I can get it right, it'll have a cascading effect.

Here is the JUnit test I need to pass for the isSpaceAvailable method.

```
@Test
public void testIsSpaceAvailable() {
    Model m = new Model(10,10,0,0,0);
    Fish f = new Fish(1, 7, 100, Fish.UP);
    Plant p = new Plant(2, 8, 100);
    m.addFish(f);
    m.addPlant(p);
    assertFalse(m.isSpaceAvailable(1, 7));
    assertFalse(m.isSpaceAvailable(2, 8));
    assertFalse(m.isSpaceAvailable(0, 0));
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 9; j++) {
            if ((i != 1 || j != 7) && (i != 2  || j != 8)) {
                assertTrue(m.isSpaceAvailable(i, j));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the JavaDoc for the project if you guys need to look through it.
http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2013/cmsc131-23/Projects/P7/doc/index.html

I've been staring at this for a while and I'm throughly stuck.

Comment: You say you are going wrong, you say you are failing, but you give us incomplete code and don't tell us WHAT is wrong.  A full example is considered necessary by some folks here, but even more consider it imperative that you tell us just what is wrong.  We can't even run it to find out ourselves.  Essentially what you've done is given us a bunch of code and asked us to see if we can find anything wrong with it -- we aren't even given any evidence that the problem is in this code.

Comment: I've tested my other methods against the provided tests, any time that the addFish method is called, that test fails.  I can post the java files if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addFish` is in a bad state. Remove the local `ArrayList`, If you are worried about thread safety/concurrency use a locking strategy or synchronise the method. The final loop is wrong and redundant, by the time you hit it you have satisfied the conditions for adding a fish.
Can you add a fish where a plant is?

```
public void addFish(Fish f) {

    if ( landscape[ f.getRow() ][ f.getCol() ] == ROCK ) {
        throw new IllegalFishPositionException(
                IllegalFishPositionException.FISH_OVER_ROCK );
    }

    for ( Fish f1 : this.fish ) {
        // is Fish.equals implemented if so use that.
        if ( f1 == f){

           // fish already in list nothing to do
           // usually bad practice to have return in middle of method
           return; 

        } else if ( ( f1.getRow() == f.getRow() && 
                f1.getCol() == f.getCol() )) {
            throw new IllegalFishPositionException(
                    IllegalFishPositionException.TWO_FISH_IN_ONE_PLACE );
        }
    }

   fish.add( f );

}
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Thank you so much!!  I do have one request: to better understand exceptions, so any time an exception is thrown, the code below it is not executed, is that right?  And also why did separating the f=f1 conditional make everything work?  I have much to learn, looking for some clarification if anyone could provide.

Comment: @KatoPlato An exception behaves like a return statement except instead of being 'caught' by the calling method it gets 'caught' by a wrapping catch block. the only thing that did was to ignore the fish if it was already in the list in your condition `f=f1` was redundant if it was true then the other side of the or condition would be true. Throwing an exception in that case does not make much sense.

Comment: It is also worth putting in the effort to understand `try` `catch` and `finally` they are very useful so you will encounter them a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have a redundant second loop in `addFish()`, which will add the fish multiple times/ or never, if there are no fish to start with.

WRONG:

```
for ( Fish f2 : addFish ) {
    if ( ( f2.getRow() != f.getRow() && 
            f2.getCol() != f.getCol() ) && 
            landscape[ f.getRow() ][ f.getCol() ] != ROCK ) {
        fish.add( f );    // adds F repeatedly!
    }
}
```

CORRECT CODE:

```
public void addFish (Fish f) {
    // we don't need to copy the 'fish' list -- but if we did, we'd call it 'copyFish' not 'addFish'.
    /* List<Fish> copyFish = new ArrayList<Fish>( fish); */

    if (landscape[ f.getRow()][ f.getCol()] == ROCK) {
        throw new IllegalFishPositionException( IllegalFishPositionException.FISH_OVER_ROCK);
    }
    for (Fish exist : fish) {
        if ((exist.getRow() == f.getRow() && exist.getCol() == f.getCol()) {
            throw new IllegalFishPositionException(
                    IllegalFishPositionException.TWO_FISH_IN_ONE_PLACE);
        }
    }
    // All OK;     clear water, no rock or other fish there.
    //    -- add the fish.
    fish.add( f);
    landscape[ f.getRow()][ f.getCol()] = FISH;
}
```

Also, clean up your code. Make it compact, literate & readable.

You need to write concise code that make meaningful sense, not long verbal & white-space filling manglings, that don't.

My personal practice is to suffix list/set/map/collection fields (not parameters) with 'List' or whatever, eg 'fishList'. This distinguishes them from lists passed as parameters, which is a common usecase.

Comment: I'd like to better my "style" meanderings.  Is there a site I can refer to help with that?

Comment: The Java style conventions http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html or more generally https://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/